# Transpose of a matrix in python

Tags: python, exception, matrix

How can I modify this to input matrices with any dimension, How can I change the n without inputting n?

Develop a program to input a matrix with any dimension and output the transpose of that matrix. You should stop accepting the rows when -1 is entered as the input. Use a 2D (two-dimensional) list to store the matrix. You should handle the exceptions such as checking the invalid rows with an inconsistent number of elements.

Note: Print “Invalid Matrix” as the error message for invalid rows with an inconsistent number of elements. Print “Error” for any other exceptions you are handling.

try:

```
lst=[]
n=4
for i in range(n) :
    
    inp=input()
    
    if inp==-1:
        break
    marks=inp.split()

    mark_list = list(map(int,marks))

    lst.append(mark_list)
    
    
for j in range(len(lst[0])):
    for k in range(len(lst)):
        print(lst[k][j],end=" ")
    print("\n",end="")
```

except EOFError :
pass
except IndexError:
print("Invalid Matrix")

Comment: You limited it to 4 rows. Just replace 'n = 4` and `for i in range(n) :` with `while True:`. Also, note you are not checking for incoherent inputs as requested (e.g., first row with 4 elements, second row with 3, or 5)

Comment: inputs are given as rows, so u just have to get the length of the first input row as n

Answer (score 2):

```
list(zip(*lst))
```

This one line transpose the whole matrix

Comment: Thank you. But I just want to  know how can I modify this code block for matrices with any dimension

Comment: this works for any dimensions

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transpose a matrix of any dimension, use `numpy`:

```
# Python env: pip install numpy
# Miniconda env: conda install numpy
# Anaconda env: already installed

import numpy as np

lst = [[[11, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16]], [[21, 22], [23, 24], [25, 26]]]

m = np.array(lst)
M = m.T
```

Output:

```
>>> m
array([[[11, 12],
        [13, 14],
        [15, 16]],

       [[21, 22],
        [23, 24],
        [25, 26]]])


>>> M
array([[[11, 21],
        [13, 23],
        [15, 25]],

       [[12, 22],
        [14, 24],
        [16, 26]]])
```